# Setup Postfix/dovecot/maysql - receiving mail in Maildir but not in client inbox

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, maildir

I'm not an expert in mail server configuration

I successfully setup the server to send mail but i cant find the solution for receiving my emails in the client inbox but i can in my Maildir.

response from mail log:

```
Feb 20 18:56:36 businesshark postfix/smtpd[5153]: connect from unknown[109.227.62.192]

Feb 20 18:56:37 businesshark postfix/smtpd[5153]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[109.227.62.192]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)

Feb 20 18:56:38 businesshark postfix/trivial-rewrite[5160]: warning: do not list domain proenergy.club in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains

Feb 20 18:56:38 businesshark postfix/smtpd[5153]: 4DB46142D82: client=unknown[109.227.62.192], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=stjepan@proenergy.club

Feb 20 18:56:38 businesshark postfix/cleanup[5163]: 4DB46142D82: message-id=<56C8A8D4.4010605@proenergy.club>

Feb 20 18:56:38 businesshark postfix/qmgr[4981]: 4DB46142D82: from=<stjepan@proenergy.club>, size=676, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Feb 20 18:56:38 businesshark postfix/local[5165]: 4DB46142D82: to=<robert@proenergy.club>, relay=local, delay=0.51, delays=0.5/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)

Feb 20 18:56:38 businesshark postfix/qmgr[4981]: 4DB46142D82: removed

Feb 20 18:56:39 businesshark postfix/smtpd[5153]: disconnect from unknown[109.227.62.192]
```

postfix main config file

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#smtpd_use_tls=yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem

smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
#smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
#tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

#smtpd_use_tls=yes
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = server.businesshark.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.businesshark.com, mail.proenergy.club, localhost.localdomain, localhost, businesshark.com, proenergy.club
#mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_transport = dovecot
#virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
```

I'm stuck with this for days I will appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: are you relaying emails. e.g using gmail?

Comment: no I'm not relaying emails with gmail

Comment: yeah its ok i saw in the settings youre not set up like that. ill have a look around and get back

Comment: thank you very much, do you need anything? any other config file?

Comment: it may be a port issue you are having -- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176051

Comment: i don't know  i have setup the server to use imap - on port 143 and port 25

Comment: I'm receiving emails in my Maildir cur folder i checked. Maybe i need to map folders or something like that. Sent folder is working normally

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately this is not the solution

Comment: add the setup guide you followed to set it all up. maybe someone can spot something

Comment: i'm not sure i followed multiple files, the first document i followed was the one on digitalocean.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin

but since than i looked all the documents on the net to figure the problem

Comment: also i looked this guide
http://kloud51.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49&language=french

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem:

/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

```
protocols = imap lmtp
```

and I changed /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Now I have another question

I need to forward mail to a virtual alias but I also need mail in the inbox.

How do I need to change the configuration to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

i figure out the problem, no need to change the configuration

i added in my alias table both addresses the one to forward to and the local address separate my coma. The second address is the same as the source address